# can anybody help me to run this django github project in window?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-registration, django-project-architect

I used these steps to run this projects:

1. downloaded and extracted and opened with vscode
2. created virtual env using virtualenv test
3. after django installation and pip install -r requirements.txt
   4)after successfully installation of requirements it is showing not found two modules celery and dotenv

File "C:\Users\christ\Downloads\opensource-job-portal-master\jobsp\settings.py", line 2, in 
from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

The link of Github-project is given below:
https://github.com/MicroPyramid/opensource-job-portal

Comment: try to install the modules individually with `pip3 install dotenv`.

Answer (score 0):

The commands vary for different versions of python or different Operating systems.

Try using `python -m pip install python-dotenv` for windows.

It might help you to solve this error.